# jQuery form validation: standard windows dialog box when field is invalid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I need a very basic client-side form validation: whenever an invalid field is encountered display a standard windows dialog box, stop checking the remaining fields, and cancel submission.

What is the easiest way to do the above with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You may try tagging all fields you need to validate with a class of "RequiredField" and then use Jquery to validate them all at once.  For the ones that fail you can add a class of highlight to turn them, say, red.

After that you can show a warning that says the highlighted fields are invaild.

```
function CheckStandardInputs(){
    //Check for required fields.
    var ReqFields = $(".RequiredField[value='']");
```

```
if(ReqFields.size() > 0){
    if(HighlightBlanks){
        ReqFields.addClass("Highlight");
    }
            //Remove highlight on change.
    ReqFields.change(function () {$(this).removeClass("Highlight");});
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion? A link to a code snippet would be great ;)

Comment: Aparently I don't know how to handle pre's very well. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the standard jQuery [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I just don't know if it's capable of doing what I need.

Comment: ... and not sure if it's not an overkill for such a simple task